# Jest cannot handle the sequelize.sync() promise

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, jestjs

I have this test file running with Jest:

```
test('this works', () => {
  Promise.resolve();
});

test('this also works', (done) => {
  setTimeout(done, 100);
});

test('this does not work', () => {
  return models.sequelize.sync({force: true, logging: false});
});

test('this also does not work', (done) => {
  models.sequelize.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => done());
});
```

Something is either weird with Sequelize.js or Jest. Ideas?

To clarify: It's not I'm getting failing tests, all 4 tests are green. The latter two will get the database reset, but the Jest process will forever hang even after all test ran. Jest will say: 4 passed, just I have to manually quit with Ctrl + C.

Comment: Are you sure the sequelize promise is actually completing? Try adding some logging in the `then`

Comment: @RichardSzalay yeah logging will still happen, so I'm assuming `done` is called, `then`  callback is also called. Just the test process will still hang after everything for whatever reason.

Comment: I think I found the issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7953 Going to keep this open for another day hoping a better solution is proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this Github issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7953
The `sync` method actually will only return when the connection idles eventually, so the solution is to:

```
models.sequelize.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
  models.sequelize.close();
});
```